# Extracting data from a SpatialPointsDataFrame into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in case some polygons have no overlapping spatial points

Tags: r, sp

Data used in this post:

- Climate data (10') from the Climatic Research Unit, which I have changed into a SpatialPointsDataFrame https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/tmc/
- Shapefile from European NUTS 3 regions, in R a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts

I am trying to get the average climate for each NUTS 3 region, by overlaying the two spatial objects and taking the average of the climate values which fall within each polygon:

```
NUTS_precipitation <- over(NUTS_map, CRU_pre, fn = mean)
```

However, I have many missing values because within some of the polygons fall no points (see the example of Belgium below, NAs in red). The solution would probably be to include also the surrounding climate values, but I have no idea which function to use for this.

I hope I am making myself clear. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Why did you change the raster to a point feature class? You could easily use the raster to get the zonal means. Something like `raster::extract(precip, polys, fun=mean)`

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, I didn't know it was a raster file? I imported the data using `read.table()`. It seems as if the precipitation values are given for specific coordinates, not areas. When I try to import the data with `raster()`, R gives the following error: "Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file".

Comment: I have found a different source which offers the same data in GeoTIFF format (http://www.ipcc-data.org/observ/clim/cru_ts2_1.html). I will try using the `raster::extract` then. Thank you for the tip!